# How to run a packet from archive manager

Tags: 16.04

I loaded a packet (sleepyhead) and it appears in the archive manager.  However I do not know how to get this program to run...  help me please.

Comment: Extract it from archive first.

Answer (score 0):

sleepyhead sleep tracking software can be installed in Ubuntu 16.04 and later from the default Ubuntu repositories or from the terminal with the following command:

```
sudo apt install sleepyhead
```

For information about usage type:

```
man sleepyhead   
cat /usr/share/doc/sleepyhead/usage.html
```

Comment: Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait
Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       
Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
sleepyhead is already the newest version (0.9.8-3).
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 0 à enlever et 20 non mis à jour.
mario@mario-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ 

this is what happens, sleepyhead still not running....

Comment: Do you have a Continuous  Positive  Airway  Pressure machine connected? Type `man sleepyhead` to list the supported models.

Comment: I will insert the card from the cpap machine in the computer slot and see what happens.... thanks Karel,  I will be back sonn with the result

Comment: I have to go out now, but I will come back later on to let you know how things are going

Answer (score 0):

You can see which files are in the `sleepyhead` package with

```
dpkg -L sleepyhead
```